# Removed Node.js v15 from list of versions, but Github Actions still shows it in list of checks

Tags: node.js, github-actions

I initially had Github Actions set up to run unit tests using node versions 14, 15, 16.

However I've since removed 15.x from the list. This is what it looks like now:

```
name: Compliance

on: pull_request

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      redis:
        image: redis
        # Set health checks to wait until redis has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "redis-cli ping"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x, 16.x]

    steps:
      ....
```

The checks list shows the proper title for versions 14 and 16, however there's a `build 15` afterward that obviously never runs (and therefore never completes) and my PRs never get a green checkmark.

```
CodeQL / Analyze (javascript) (pull_request) Successful in 1m
Compliance / build (14.x) (pull_request) Successful in 2m
Compliance / build (16.x) (pull_request) Successful in 1m
build (15.x) Expected — Waiting for status to be reported
Code scanning results / CodeQL Successful in 3s — No new or fixed alerts
```

I've searched through my `.github/*` files with no mention of 15 anywhere. I'm at a loss as to where I can find and remove this ghost entry for a no longer relevant version in the matrix.

Comment: Does the problem persist if your create another workflow with the new implementation, instead of editing the former one?

Comment: @GuiFalourd I just gave that a shot, deleted the old file, and split the tasks into two separate files (one for linting, one for unit tests). No mention of 15.x anywhere, and yet it still shows up in the list of checks for the PR. I can't imagine that this is due to a config setting in the repo files, yet I can't find any relevant settings in the github website for this repo either.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I also tried renaming the job from `build` to something else. The new job shows up correctly for node 14.x and 16.x, but now I have 3 ghost entries for `build (14.x)`, `build (15.x)`, `build (16.x)` ... somewhere that build job exists even though it's no longer in the config anywhere.

Comment: There might be some workflows caches on the repo that we aren't aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here was that the master branch has a set of required checks, which you must name specifically by their job (and node version) name. eg. `build 15.x`.

It took some digging as this is not directly obvious, however in the repository settings -> branches -> master [edit] page, you can add/remove the status checks which must pass.